# Merge two queries in one, GROUP BY and SUM one attribute

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a database application that manages projects and its ressources (= the employees). I have an overview that displays all employees, the projects they are assigned to and how many hours they are assigned to that project.

The overview consists of two queries (recordsets) that are put together in a loop in the VBA-code.

1. query, rstEmployees:

> ```
> SELECT employeeID, employeeName, SUM(janPlan), First(janRest), ... , SUM(decPlan), FIRST(decRest) 
> FROM tblRessources 
> INNER JOIN tblEmployees ON employeeID = employeeID
> GROUP BY employeeID, employeeName
> ```

It loops for each employee. In every loop all the correspoding projects of the employee are read and written in a temporary table. I use the following query:

2. query, rstRessources

> ```
> SELECT projectName, janPlan, janRest, ... , decPlan, decRest
> FROM tblRessources
> INNER JOIN tblProjects ON projectID = projectID
> WHERE employeeID = rstEmployees(employeeID)
> ```

- Plan: Number of hours assigned to the project
- Rest: Number of free hours

My desired result is a continuous form that looks like this:

[image: Overview]
This procedure takes too long (up to 30 seconds) and I would like to do this only with SQL queries or a pivot table. I want to get rid of the loop because that takes too much time. Is that even possible only with SQL? Do you have any ideas how to accomplish that?

Changing the underlying  tables is a possibility if it helps in any way. Also I know the tables violate atomicity and all the good normalization stuff but it works for my current solution.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: UNION ALL the two selects?

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: UNION ALL does not work because there is no looping query that searches for all the corresponding projects.

Comment: The desired result: see picture

Comment: How about JOIN the two queries?

Comment: If I Join the queries I would have to `SELECT SUM(janPlan), janPlan, janRest, ...` for all the months. That is not the desired result.

Comment: Just a clarification to my last comment: I use a continuous form. Therefore I cannot just select everything and put it in the textboxes because it would appear in every row. In the row with the employees I need the sums. In the row with the projects I do not need the sums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iBener gave me the deciding clues to solve my problem. I translated his MYSQL-query into access-SQL and this one works:

```
SELECT employeeID, 
SWITCH(typ = 0, 'typ 0', typ = 1, 'typ 1') AS typSwitch, 
SWITCH(typ = 0, employeeName, typ = 1, projektName) AS employeeProjekt, rankName,
SumJanPlan, FJanRest

FROM( 
SELECT 0 AS typ, ma.employeeName, NULL AS projektName, ma.dKX, 
  ma.employeeName, ma.employeeName AS rankName,
  SUM(janPlan) AS SumJanPlan, FIRST(janRest) AS fJanRest
FROM tblEmployees AS ma LEFT JOIN tblRessourcs AS res ON ma.dKX = res.dKX
WHERE res.jahr = 2015
GROUP BY ma.employeeName, ma.dKX

UNION ALL

SELECT 1 AS typ, NULL AS employeeName, pro.projektName, res.dKX, 
  ma.employeeName AS rankName, SUM(janPlan) AS SumJanPlan, FIRST(janRest) AS fJanRest
FROM tblProjekte AS pro 
  INNER JOIN (tblEmployees AS ma 
  INNER JOIN tblRessources AS res ON ma.employeeID = res.employeeID) ON pro.projektNr = res.projektNr

WHERE res.[jahr]=2015 AND res.employeeID IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT employeeID FROM tblRessources
  WHERE jahr = 2015) 
GROUP BY pro.projektName, ma.employeeName, res.dkx)

ORDER BY rankName, typ
```

Note

- I had to add an additional nameRank column so that all the
  employees are shown in alphabetical order. Otherwise the order is
  detemined by employeeID.
- level is a reserved word in Access-SQL so I used typ
- Instead of CASE WHEN you use SWITCH( IF, THEN, ESLE IF, THEN, ...)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
select r.level,case when r.level=0 then r.employeeName when r.level=1 then r.projectName end name,r.janPlan 
from 
(
    select 0 level,e.employeeID,e.employeeName,0 projectID,'' projectName,SUM(r.janPlan) janPlan
    from tblRessources r
    join tblEmployees e ON e.employeeID = r.employeeID
    group by e.employeeID,e.employeeName
    union all
    select 1 level,e.employeeID,e.employeeName,p.projectID,p.projectName,SUM(r.janPlan) janPlan
    from tblRessources r
    join tblEmployees e ON e.employeeID = r.employeeID
    join tblProjects p ON p.projectID = r.projectID
    group by e.employeeID,e.employeeName,p.projectID,p.projectName
) r
order by r.employeeName,r.projectName
```

Result looks like this:
[image]

Comment: This looks promising. I did not know about select case in a query.
For Access it seems to be Switch(). I will try this next week when it is not Friday evening.!

Comment: The OP needs MS Access Query, the above would be applicable to MSSQL.

Comment: hmm, sorry, I didn't see 'ms-access' tag.